# delay in docker-compose restart_policy seems to be ignored

Tags: docker, docker-compose, restart

I have a custom docker image (imagexy). This image runs once, exits and gets restarted by systemd. I want to get rid of the systemd component and tried to achieve this with the docker-compose restart-policy. I have the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:      
  consumer:
    image: imagexy
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 6000s
```

my problem is now that the compose seems to ignore the delay parameter after the run is finished.

```
2023-05-09 12:46:59,914 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-05-09 12:47:04,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)
```

COMMIT is the last log msg of a run. Afterwards the container is exited. The next log message is the first message of the next run. So it is restarted less than 5s after the container was existed.

What am i doing wrong here? I thought it should wait 6000s (10 minutes) before it restarts the container. Am i understanding the delay parameter correctly? At the moment it seems to be doing the same thing as `restart: always`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. In the end I just used systemd to start the container after some time.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docs/issues/11777